# Sublinear behavior (MongoDB cluster)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following setup:

Import CSV-file (20GB) with 90 million rows -> data takes 9GB in MongoDB -> index on „2d“ column -> additional integer-column index for sharding -> distribute data with 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 16 shards.
Each shard machine in cluster has 20GB disk space and 2GB RAM.

I generated a random query and benchmarked the execution time for each cluster configuration (see attachment).

Now my question:
Using 1, 2, 4, 6, and 8 shards I see a more or less linear decrease of runtime, as expected. With 8 shards I would assume that on each shard my data fits into memory. Therefore I thought there would be no improvement from 8 shards to 16 shards.
But from my benchmarks I observe a very strong sublinear decrease of runtime. 
Do you have an idea how this behavior might be explained? Any suggestions or references to the manual are much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Lydia

[image]

Comment: This is extremely broad. This depends on shard key selection, actual distribution of data, hardware and etc, etc, etc. There are way to many factors involved and you would have to provide a lot more information on this for an accurate and reproducible test.

Comment: The shard key is an integer in (0,99) named class_id. This means around 90,000 entries per class_id.